# WPF Ribbon - Customize the default template

Tags: ribbon, styling, controltemplate, wpf-4.5

I'm trying to customize the WPF Ribbon control. For some changes I need to access the default template of the ribbon. E.g. to remove the lower border.

I used Expression Blend to generate the Ribbon template, but the template I got has errors. There are some bindings that are not working: "{Binding (0)}".

How can I get the correct ribbon template to change colors and remove borders?

Best regards.